# When to use standalone web service approach

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

I just started learning web services. In bottom up approach, I have found some examples without being deployed in any application server. I mean a standalone web service application.
Here is an [example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world) of such type.
I have also given a try and done a walk-through of deployable simple web service examples.

So far to my learning of web services, I got to know that firstly, bottom-up- approach is not recommended. Now, in bottom-up approach, this standalone web service. When is it applicable to follow standalone web service procedure?

```
Endpoint.publish();
```

I guess, this approach is provided just for beginners and not to follow as a real-time practice. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: The most plausible use case for a standalone ws deployment is if you plan to embed your web service within another component; a component that will not be deployed within a container. Besides that, the case for a standalone web service is pretty weak: You're responsible for designing the threading/concurrency model for servicing requests.
You will also have to homegrow your own security model, you'll not benefit from container provided security mechanisms

Answer (score 1):

I would make my application as a standalone web service if it will have multiple clients like:

- Web Client via a web browser
- Mobile App Client
- Desktop Client

Then I could build every one of them alone using whatever the technology I prefer, and make it consumes my standalone web service.

For example, You could imagine the guys behind Twitter started developing it by building their core system as web service, then they build an independent web interface application for it, then they built the Twitter Android and iPhone APP, and another one came and introduced a Twitter Desktop client like Tweetbot and TweetDeck ... etc

Comment: I fail to see how your use cases prove that a standalone web service deployment is preferable over a container-deployed web service. How does the use of a browser/mobile/thick client make any difference? Your use cases are easily serviced by an EJB. Care to elaborate on your answer?

Comment: You could check the **conclusion** part of this article , it lists multiple use cases of standalone web service.
https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/07/03/jax-ws-web-services-without-ee-containers.html